# Validating whether the first nested page row in BigQuery contains a custom dimension value

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a SQL query in Big Query using StandardSQL to compute against my Google Analytics data. I'm still learning work in BigQuery and adjusting to the complexity.

I want to iterate over each session in my GA table for a range of days, and identify the FIRST hit of type "PAGE". On that hit, I want to return the value of a specific custom dimension. The custom dimension is session scoped, but I want to only know the value on this specific hit.

I think I need to parition by session and try as follows, but I am stuck regarding the second nesting

```
SELECT (SELECT value from hits.customDimension where hits.customDimension.index == 13) OVER(fullVisitorID) FROM
      `ga_sessions_2017*` AS t
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0901'
      AND '0930'
      AND totals.hits > 2) 
      AND row_number() = 1
      AND hit.type = "PAGE"
GROUP BY 1
```

I have tried the following using a UDF, but I know what I have written is completely inefficient.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  isDefined(json_str STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
var row = JSON.parse(json_str);
var defined  = "no";

for(i=0; i < row.length; i++) {
if(row[i].type != "PAGE") continue;
row[i].customDimensions.forEach(function(cd) {
if(cd.index == "13" || cd.index == 13) {
if(cd.value !== null || cd.value !== "") defined  = "yes";
}
});
return defined;
}


""";
SELECT becomesDefined, count(*) FROM (
SELECT
  isDefined(TO_JSON_STRING(t.hits)) as becomesDefined
FROM
  `ga_sessions_2017*` AS t
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0901'
  AND '0930'
  AND totals.hits > 2) GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the custom dimension is session scoped, then there will be only one value for the whole row, because one row equals one session.
This query gets the first hit cd13 value on hit scope like you specified + custom dimensions value from session level (also 13, but you can easily change that). You can use Sub-selects for everything:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT cd.value 
   FROM  t.hits h,  h.customDimensions cd 
   WHERE type='PAGE' AND cd.index=13
   ORDER BY hitnumber ASC
   LIMIT 1) AS firstHitCd13,

  (SELECT value
   FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions)
   WHERE index=13) AS sessionLevelCd13

FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_201712*` t
LIMIT
  1000
```

The first sub-select uses cross join with custom dimensions array. the second one simply unnests the customDimensions array.
One result table row equals one session/row from the source table